# Translate aspx.net page coordinate into itextsharp's pdf coordinates

Tags: asp.net, itext

How do i translate an x,y coordinates of the asp.net page (where 0,0 is the top,left corner of a page) into x,y coordinates (where 0,842 is the top left corner of itextsharp pdf page) of an pdf file created using itextsharp?
I am passing in a few coordinates into a button click to create a pdf file using itextshparp and i want to draw pictures using those coordinate into the output pdf file but the coordinate are not the same so i am putting them in the wrong location.
Thank you,

Comment: `"I am passing in a few coordinates into a button click to create a pdf file"` - How are you currently trying to do that?  Any coordinates are going to have to come from client-side code, since the server-side code has no knowledge of how the page was actually rendered (browser dimensions, etc.).

Comment: I am passing those coordinates in using javascript function using jquery ajax which in turn call a server side web method.

Comment: In what way is that not working?  Is it just that the coordinates aren't what you expect them to be?  Can you provide an example?

Comment: let's say i am passing a x,y coordinate of 300,200 and i want to draw a picture at that same coordinate in the output pdf. When open the pdf file the picture was drawn in the different location becuause pdf use 0 and 842 as the location of the top left coorner. So how to transform my coordinate into pdf's coordinate so that the picture is drawn at that same location (300,200) with respect to the top left corner?

Comment: Ah, it appears that the coordinates are flipped on the Y axis in a PDF.  0,0 is the *bottom*-left corner.  This might require some clever math, if it's possible at all.  Do you know the pixel-height of your PDF page beforehand?  If so then you might be able to just say that `PDFY = KnownHeight - InputY`.  Seems like this is going to be fairly unreliable in general since a PDF page dimension is static but a browser's dimensions are fluid.

Comment: an itextsharp's pdf page is 595px in width and 842px in height

Comment: What does iTextSharp using coordinate like that?

Comment: Because that's how the PDF standard is defined.  It's not iTextSharp's fault, they're just following the standard.

Comment: then the question is now becomes "How do i convert from a top,left coordinate system into a bottom,left coordinate system?

Comment: You mean something other than `new_y = page_height - old_y`?

Comment: I have been using the same equation but it does not work consistently that is why i asked the question from the begining.

Comment: We'll need more information as to what "not working consistently" means.

Comment: I think i got it Chris. The problem was the way i position the picture on the page. It is working correctly now. Thank you Chris and David